# HADOOP - Writing YARN applications

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am reading [this](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WritingYarnApplications.html#How_do_I_include_native_libraries) and I am a little bit confused. Do I have to write always Client and ApplicationMaster Class to run my own code in YARN? For example if I want to run an application which just generates random numbers, Do I have to include these classes to my code or it can run it without these? Or, are they both different examples because I can see 2 main classes in there (1 main in each class)? I tried it with all of those ways but I am still getting something like an error --> `usage [input][ouput]:`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Writing a native YARN apps may be a little awkward because Hadoop YARN project doesn't have a higher level framework to help with this. However there are few projects which are doing the heavy lifting so that user would not have a need to worry about this boilerplate code.

- [Spring YARN](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hadoop/) as part of Spring for Apache Hadoop with [YARN Samples](https://spring.io/guides?filter=yarn)
- [Apache Twill](http://twill.incubator.apache.org/)
- [Slider](https://wiki.apache.org/incubator/SliderProposal)

  In a link you posted, yes there are two main classes, one for running the client which deploys and starts the app on YARN, other for appmaster.

Answer (score 1):

You could use provided examples in jar file located at $Yarn_Home/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.1.jar.

example:

yarn jar $Yarn_Home/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-0.23.1.jar wordcount /in /out

/in and /out are located in hdfs. You need to put some text files in /in and /out must not exist before.

Check this for reference:
http://hortonworks.com/blog/introducing-apache-hadoop-yarn/

https://github.com/hortonworks/simple-yarn-app

Comment: yes, but what about my own code?
If I want for example to write a simple random_number_generator, what are the mandatory classes which must be in my code to run this in yarn? I cannot understand if I have to write by my own the Client and ApplicationMaster... Why this is not implemented by the yarn framework itself?

Comment: I believe this is due to how Hadoop project for V2 was initially done. They created a YARN which really is a dummy resource scheduler order to overcome scaling problems in Hadoop V1. Some of the JobTracker/TaskTracker responsibilities were moved over to a per application appmaster. YARN never had any generic client/appmaster and even MapReduce V2 has its own client/appmaster. YARN is a foundational framework so I think it's best to keep higher level framework code on other projects.

Comment: So, I always have to write a Client and an ApplicationMaster to make it properly work

Comment: I'd also take a grain of salt with Hortonworks simple-yarn-app sample because it hasn't been updated to work with Hadoop 2.2. There is pull requests in github and user need to apply those manually if using any other than Hadoop 2.1(which nobody should not even try).

Comment: Yes, you always need to have a Client and an Application Master even if those are provided by some other higher level framework.